# Remove subsection text indentation

Tags: sectioning, indentation

I'm trying to remove the `left-indentation` inserted automatically before the `subsection`'s text. `\noindent` and `parindent` are not working (I guess they're made to work with `paragraphs` not with `sections`).

See in the next screenshot in red the indentation (spacing) I'm trying to get rid of:

[image: ![screenshot]

The only code I'm using to style the `subsections` (and `sections`) is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

% customize sections style
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}

% experience and education items
\newcommand{\experienceline}[3]{
    \subsection*{
        #1 \hfill \small #2 \newline
        \normalsize #3
    }
}

\begin{document}
    % hobbies section
    \section*{Hobbies}
    \experienceline{Reading}{2011-2011}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you any code to define your (sub)sections formatting?

Comment: @Bernard I've just added the bit of code used to style the sections' margins.

Comment: This code alone doesn't reproduce your problem when insertes in a full compilable code. Could you post a minimal compilable code which reproduces it?

Comment: @Bernard please see the update, it should reproduce the indentation I described in the subsection called "Reading" above.

Comment: @h4k1m No, the code snippet doesn't reproduce the behavior. You have a wealth of unprotected end-of-lines, though. And other quirks, such as believing that `\small` and `\normalsize` take an argument: they don't.

Comment: @egreg The exactly same code above does show the indentation of the subsection for me. I'm using `miktex` on Windows (I'm not sure this might be because of it).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't reproduce it with this code – and I 'm using MiKTeX.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right, it seems that if I put the code between curly brackets in the same line as the `\subsection` there's no spacing. The indentation seems to be created by the `<CR>` character.

Comment: the point is you are supposed to post an example of the problem. If you post code that does not have a problem and post an image generated by some different code you have not shown, how can anyone help?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle please see my previous comment!

Comment: the end of line is a space (not indentation, a normal word space as I said in my initial comment, but since the section head _in your code_ starts a paragraph, word spaces are ignored.  But you used different code, that you have not shown to generate the image.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The code as written above produces the indentation for me (There's nothing to update!). Regarding the percentage sign (%), it does solve my problem as well. Thank you.

Comment: what makes the black horizontal line shown in your image?

Comment: [Your code produces this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydpnW.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry I've updated the screenshot. But the indentation still persists if I omit the `%` sign.